# How to convert datetime to string in python in django

Tags: python, django

I have a datetime object at my model.
I am sending it to the view, but in html i don't know what to write in order to format it.

I am trying

```
{{ item.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")|escape }}
```

but I get

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: item.date.strftime|("%Y-%m-%d")||escape
```

when I am just using

```
{{ item.date|escape }}
```

it's working, but now with the format I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the built-in Django [date format filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) instead:

```
{{ item.date|date:"Y M d" }}
```